# Prescriptions-r-x chain of pharmacies E-R diagram to SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

[ER Diagram -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTn2h.png)

Hi Everyone , i started learning Database few weeks ago , and had this exercise today . I have to convert E-R diagram to SQL . Can someone check my code if its ok ?
I am confused at part of weak entity **DRUG** .

```html
create database Ilacet
go
use ilacet
go
--definimi i tabelave

create table Patient
(
ssn varchar(10),
phy_ssn varchar(10),
age tinyint,
name varchar(20) not null,
address varchar(25),
constraint SSN_PK primary key (ssn),
constraint PHY_FK foreign key (phy_ssn) references Doctor
)
go

create table Doctor
(
phy_ssn varchar(10),
speciality varchar(20) not null,
name varchar(20) not null,
exp_year tinyint(2),
constraint PHY_SSN_PK primary key (phy_ssn)
)
go



create table Pharmacy
(
name varchar(20),
address varchar(20) not null,
phone_number varchar(20) not null,
constraint NAME_PK primary key (name)
)
go

create table Pharm_co
(
pname varchar(20),
phone_num varchar(15) not null,
constraint PNAME_PK primary key(pname)
)
go

create table Drug
(
trade_name varchar(20),
pname varchar(20),
formula varchar(20),
constraint D_PK primary key(trade_name,pname),
constraint DP_S foreign key (pname) references Pharm_co
) 
go

create table Prescription
(
ssn varchar(10),
phy_ssn varchar(20),
trade_name varchar(20),
pname varchar(10)
data date,
quantity integer,
constraint PK_PK primary key(ssn,phy_ssn,trade_name,pname),
constraint Pn_F foreign key (ssn) references Patient,
constraint DO_F foreign key(phy_ssn) references Doctor,
constraint PO_F foreign key(pname) references Pharm_co,
constraint DR_F foreign key(trade_name) references Drug
)
go

create table Contract
(
name varchar(20),
pname varchar(20),
start_date date,
end_date date,
text varchar(15),
supervisor varchar(15),
constraint PN_PK primary key(name,pname)
constraint NAME_P foreign key (name) references Pharmacy,
constraint P_N foreign key(pname)references Pharm_co
)
go
create table Sell
(
name varchar(20),
trade_name varchar(20)
pname varchar(20),
price integer,
constraint PK_KK primary key(name,trade_name,pname) ,
constraint Pharmacy_name foreign key (name) references Pharmacy,
constraint Drug_name foreign key(trade_name)references Drug,
constraint Pharm_id foreign key(pname) references Pharm_co
)
go
```

Comment: In the creation of the table `Drug` you need to specify which field of `Pharm_co` is referenced by the foreign key, i.e. change `REFERENCES Pharm_co` to `REFERENCES Pharm_co ( name )`.  Same story with `Patient` referencing `Doctor`.

Comment: Also, create tables referenced by foreign keys before you create the table that does the referencing.  i.e. Create `Doctor` before `Patient` and so on.